# Линии в Google Maps

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api

У меня есть List `routePoints`, который собирает местоположения:

```
ArrayList<LatLng> routePoints;
```

И где нужно рисовать линию, делаю так:

```
PolylineOptions pOptions = new PolylineOptions()
    .width(5)
    .color(Color.BLACK)
    .addAll(routePoints)
    .geodesic(true);
```

Все это конечно работает корректно, например, если идешь по тротуару, линия чертится немного правее/левее от главной улицы. И через какой то время у меня идет обновление линии на карте и в тот момент я уже на параллельной улице и вместо того чтобы чертить линии по улицам, срезает, то есть, от предущего местоположения к нынешнему, и кажется что я прошел сквозь здания. Надеюсь, поняли...)

Но мне хотелось бы, чтобы чертились линии по улицам(идем по какой то улице, потом, на право и тд)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Попробовал [android-maps-utils](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils) таким образом:

```
String encodedLine = PolyUtil.encode(routePoints);
List<LatLng> encodedList = PolyUtil.decode(encodedLine);

PolylineOptions pOptions = new PolylineOptions()
    .width(5)
    .color(Color.BLACK)
    .addAll(encodedList)
    .geodesic(true);
```

Никаких изменений. Может у кого есть решение или мнение?

Answer (score 0):

По точкам так рисовать ломано и будет. Чтобы рисовало по улице, вероятно, нужно брать несколько опорных точек и по таймеру запрашивать по ним route через `Google Maps Directions API`. И уже отрисовывать его.

Comment: Смотрите, дело в том, у меня определение местоположения обновляется каждые 2 минуты и за 2 минуты я могу оказаться на параллельной улице и линия обрежет здания, дома. А мне нужно чтобы по улицам чертил

Comment: вы не сможете по двум точкам нарисовать маршрут по улице. либо тогда чекайте маршрут чаще, либо рисуйте через `Direction API`